# Eloquent Laravel Fetch Data from multiple tables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I've spent two days trying to solve this but I can't figure how.

I have five tables

- Product
- Category
- Category_Product
- Order
- Order_Product

From the view,clicking on a category button I have to fetch all his ordered products with the relative category.

I have the current models:

**Product Model**

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function categories() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
    }

    public function orders() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Order');
    }
}
```

**Category Model**

```
public function products() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product');
}
```

**Order Model**

```
public function products() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product');
}
```

Now the problem is that I can't figure how to fetch the data from the current tables.When I press a button I'm able to fetch the category from the `Product` Table,but I want to fetch from the `Ordered_Products`. I really can't figure how.

With this I'm able to fetch all the categories from Product

```
if (request()->category) {
    $products = Product::with('categories')->whereHas('categories', function ($query) {
        $query->where('slug', request()->category);
    })->get();
}
```

With this instead,I'm able to fetch the ordered products.

```
$products = DB::table('order_product')
    ->join('products', 'order_product.product_id','=', 'products.id')
    ->where('order_product.user_id','=',$user_id)
    ->get();
```

For the latter, there's a better way to do it, that's for sure. I'm sorry if it's a dumb question but I'm rather new with this framework. I am using Laravel 7.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using whereHas two times:

```
$products = Product::with('categories')->whereHas('categories',function($query){
                $query->where('slug',request()->category);
            })->whereHas('orders',function($query){
                $query->where('orders.user_id',Auth::id());
            })->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically Eloquent Model doesn't encourage joining tables to retrieve data. It should be joined only for filtering results (So you need to drop field of other table using `->select('original_table.*')`)

In this case, you should simply retrieve `categories` at first. Then retrieve related data using relation property accessing.

e.g.

```
$categories = Category::query()
    ->with('products')
    ->where('slug', request('category'))
    ->get();
$products = $categories->flatMap->products;
$pivots = $products->map->pivot;
```